# pass value through rails to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I a have a link , on which when i click it passes a text to a variable named :alert like this :

```
<%= link_to 'Get started now !',play_path , :alert => 'OK'  %>
```

on the page at `play_path` i test to see if the value :alert exists , and if it does , i pass that value to a javascript function . My question is how can i pass that value to a javascript function ?

here is what i would like to do :

```
<%  if :alert -%>
<script>
$.pnotify({
                        pnotify_title: ' <%= :alert %> ',
                        pnotify_text: 'it's ok',
                        pnotify_type: 'error'
                    });
</script>
    <% end -%>
```

of course the code isn't correct , it's just for 'explanation' of what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your controller you should have.

```
@alert = params[:alert]
```

I guess you have to use the link like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Get started now !',play_path(:alert => 'OK')  %>
```

And you can use the `@alert` variable in your views.

```
<%  if @alert -%>
<script>
$.pnotify({
   pnotify_title: ' <%= @alert %> ',
   pnotify_text: 'it's ok',
   pnotify_type: 'error'
});
</script>
<% end -%>
```